# Is there a way to create a CosmosDb Snapshot and restore it using a C# Console app?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I searched everywhere and I couldn't find a single article that shows a way to create a script/console app that creates a snapshot of a CosmosDb database and restores it -- is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Cosmos DB doesn't have the ability to snapshot a database. You'd need to create this on your own.

While "how" you accomplish this is a bit off-topic, as it's very broad, there are two built-in Azure approaches:

- Change Feed. Cosmos DB has a Change Feed you may subscribe to, to consume content from a container in a streaming approach. By consuming the change feed, you could effectively re-create a container's data into another container. There are several writeups around this very topic.
- Data Factory. You can copy content between containers via an Azure Data Factory pipeline (Cosmos DB is available as both a *source* and a *sink* for pipelines).

Comment: Thank you -- this is a good place to start. I will explore the second option since I have more experience in ADF